# ng-repeat not updating properly in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to put pagination with `ng-repeat`. Getting result but by the time showing old data and suddenly hide and show new set data, like jerking. My angularjs version is "1.5.8".

```
$scope.gap = 5;

        $scope.filteredItems = [];
        $scope.groupedItems = [];
        $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
        $scope.pagedItems = [];
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        var resultData = [...];
        var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
            if (!needle) {
                return true;
            }
            return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        };

        // init the filtered items
        $scope.search = function () {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(resultData, function (item) {
                for(var attr in item) {
                    if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            // take care of the sorting order

            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            // now group by pages
            $scope.groupToPages();
        };

        $scope.groupToPages = function () {
            $scope.pagedItems = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
                if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                    $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
                } else {
                    $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
                }
            }
            console.log($scope.pagedItems)
        };

        $scope.range = function (size,start, end) {
            var ret = [];        
            //console.log(size,start, end);

            if (size < end) {
                end = size;
                start = size-$scope.gap;
            }
            for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                ret.push(i);
            }        
            // console.log(ret);        
            return ret;
        };

        $scope.prevPage = function () {
            if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                $scope.currentPage--;
            }
        };

        $scope.nextPage = function () {
            if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
                $scope.currentPage++;
            }               
        };

        $scope.setPage = function () {
            console.log($scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage]);
            $scope.currentPage = this.n;
        };

        $scope.search();
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in pagedItems[currentPage]" >
        <td>{{user.name}} {{$index}}</td>
      </tr>
```

As above code, that table row update as 5 row. but when I click next or page numbers showing 10 rows and hide 5 rows. I hope you understand guys! Help me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are thinking wrong, it's simpler to use custom filter and break up your business logic like this

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
    });
```

then in the controller you can do

```
$scope.showResults = function() {
                        $scope.list = $filter('startFrom')($scope.initialList, $scope.page * $scope.itemsPerPage);
                        $scope.list = $filter('limitTo')($scope.list, $scope.itemsPerPage);
                    }
                };
```

now you need only to update $scope.page and reuse $scope.showResults() to update the view

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in list" >
    <td>{{user.name}} {{$index}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your problem is cause by ng-repeat. I just take your code, add some dummy data and do a test and it's totally work fine.

You can check it here https://codepen.io/Cushdrive/pen/zvPPXd

Because angular is two way binding, so I'm wonder that could it be some paging info was triggered somewhere. Could you double check on some variable like `currentPage` `itemPerPages` or `pagedItems` to see if it being used somewhere else?